# php json decode with sort by

Tags: php, sorting, json

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
 if (strtolower($a->n) == strtolower($b->n)) return 0;
 return (strtolower($a->n) < strtolower($b->n)) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

This works well for some json data like this

```
$txt = '[{"n":"1"},{"n":"2"},{"n":"3"},{"n":"4"},{"n":"5"},{"n":"6"},{"n":"7"},{"n":"8"},{"n":"9"},{"n":"10"},{"n":"11"}]
$j = json_decode($txt);
usort($j, 'mySort');
foreach ($j as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v->n.'<br />';//1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
}
```

But when some data like this:

```
$txt = '[{"n":"a 1"},{"n":"a 2"},{"n":"a 3"},{"n":"a 4"},{"n":"a 5"},{"n":"a 6"},{"n":"a 7"},{"n":"a 8"},{"n":"a 9"},{"n":"a 10"},{"n":"a 11"}]';
$j = json_decode($txt);
usort($j, 'mySort');
foreach ($j as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v->n.'<br />';//a 1  a 10  a 11  a 2  a 3  a 4  a 5  a 6  a 7  a 8  a 9
}
```

I need a sort as

```
a 1  a 2  a 3  a 4  a 5  a 6  a 7  a 8  a 9  a 10  a 11
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or even simpler, use [strnatcmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php). It performs natural ordering and compare the elements in a way that seems natural to humans.

Example:

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
  return strnatcmp($a->n, $b->n);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed, +1

Comment: There's also a sorting algorithm for this purpose: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mySort2($a, $b) {
    list ($k, $n) = explode (' ', $a->n);
    list ($l, $m) = explode (' ', $b->n);
    if (strtolower($n) == strtolower($m)) return 0;
    return (strtolower($n) < strtolower($m)) ? -1 : 1;
}
$txt = '[{"n":"a 1"},{"n":"a 2"},{"n":"a 3"},{"n":"a 4"},{"n":"a 5"},{"n":"a 6"},{"n":"a 7"},{"n":"a 8"},{"n":"a 9"},{"n":"a 10"},{"n":"a 11"}]';
$j = json_decode($txt);
usort($j, 'mySort2');
foreach ($j as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v->n.'<br />';//a 1  a 10  a 11  a 2  a 3  a 4  a 5  a 6  a 7  a 8  a 9
}
```